# Why cant I create a trigger on a VIEW in SQLite?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

Upon executing:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TRIGGER DirectoryInsertTrigger INSERT ON Directory 
BEGIN

END;
```

I get the error: `cannot create BEFORE trigger on view: Directory`. (AFTER doesnt work either). Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to use the `INSTEAD OF` keyword.

Comment: Right. I think the same goes for MS SQL, Oracle and probably others.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224775%28v=sql.80%29.aspx